# Writing to csv in R creates unwanted scientifc notations in excel

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a data frame in R that I want to save as a CSV. In rstudio, some of the columns keep displaying as scientific notations. I am using `options(scipen = 999)` to not have this issue. Unfortunetly when I try using `write.csv` or `write.csv` some of the number and character columns get changed to scientific notation. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What does the CSV file look like if you open it in say Notepad?

Comment: @BigBen it displays fine on notepad..ugh excel is so annoying

Comment: Mental note for the future: CSV is *not* an Excel file.